# How can I start a windows service from a web application?

Tags: web-applications, windows-services

Dears,

I am developing a web application that interacts with the user and at some point it will be necessary to start a process in the background. This process in BG will feed a database, while the web application continues interacting with the user and reading the data that was entered by the process in BG. I thought of using a windows service to do this function in BG, I wonder if it is possible to start a windows service from a web application?

Comment: Are you wanting to start the service on the browser computer or on the server? I do not think you will get very far trying to start a program or service on the browser system. That would present too much security risk.

Comment: Is the web application feeding data to a database?  Why don't you just do it real-time, why does it have to be a background process?  How long does it take to process?

Comment: Even if the process takes long to run, your web-app should be able to deal with it assynchronally, shouldn't it? Which technologies are you using in your web application, @danilopf? Maybe (probably, actually) there's a better way to do what you're intended, but we need more information to help you. Does the process you want to run stay at the server or at the client?

Comment: lit: I would like to start windows service on the server.

Comment: Rick S - Actually I need both processes running at the same time, one that will feed the database (I thought of a windows service), and another that will interact with the users (a web application). The issue is that the process that will feed the database, should be started from a user request or command that has a specific profile, some parameters need to be prepared before the process in BG is run. It may be a different solution, not necessary a windows service. The process can last an hour, two hours, it must capture tweets in real time on a emergency situation. It's my doctoral thesis.

Comment: Pstr - if it is possible to manage the process by web application, would be great, but I'm not finding a way to do it. I am using vb .net, linqtotwitter and sql server. In linqtoTwiter I will need to post tweets, and capture certain tweets from the past with some specific criteria. These will run on web application. In the Background I need to capture in real time the tweets that are being generated at that moment, depending on the emergency situation and load the database.